# n(n-3)/2 - dimensional representation of Sn

Tags: representation-theory

I'm trying to understand the following decomposition of $M^{(n-2,2)}$

[here is the part of the article with the relevant decomposition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma3h5.png)

I don't understand why the last representation (which is $\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$-dimensional) is irreducible.

help very appreciated.

Comment: Well, $M^{(n-2,2)}$ has simple summand $S^{(n-2,2)}$ which has dimension $n(n-3)/2$. Having identified the compliment, the author is done.

Comment: But why is it irreducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using general theory, we know that $M^{(n-2,2)}$ contains a copy of the $n(n-3)/2$-dimensional representation $S^{(n-2,2)}$. Now, the author finds an $n$-dimensional submodule isomorphic to $M^{(n-1,1)}=S^{(n)}\oplus S^{(n-1,1)}$.

Using general theory again, the compliment of $M^{(n-1,1)}$ is an $S_n$-submodule. Since 
$\dim M^{(n-2,2)}={n\choose 2}$, this compliment has dimension ${n\choose 2}-n=\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$. Since there is no room left for anything else, this compliment must be the irreducible representation $S^{(n-2,2)}$.